# Option tag doesnt display in my flask project

Tags: python, html, sqlite, flask

I tried to make a groceries list app, but when it came to displaying my db like option in select tag, it still displayed as a paragraph

I tried to rewrite the whole code and I tried to reinstall flask, but nothing has helped. Even reinstalling python didnt help. I hope that somebody will help me to solve this problem and I will continue developing my app and learning Flask.

```
import sqlite3
import random
from flask import Flask, session, render_template, request, g

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'RYO1s6LXzR'

@app.route('/')
def index():
    data = get_db()
    return render_template('index.html', all_data=data)

@app.route('/add_items', methods=["post"])
def add_items():
    return request.form["select_items"]

def get_db():
    db = getattr(g, '_database', None)
    if db is None:
        db = g._database = sqlite3.connect('grocery_list.db')
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute('SELECT name FROM groceries')
        all_data = cursor.fetchall()
        all_data = [str(val[0]) for val in all_data]
    return all_data

@app.teardown_appcontext
def close_connection(exception):
    db = getattr(g, '_database', None)
    if db is not None:
        db.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Grocery List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="add_item">
        <form action="/add_items" method="post">
            <select name="select_items">
                {% for item in all_data %}
                <option value="{{ item }}">{{ item }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>

            <input type="submit" value="ADD ITEM">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
import sqlite3

groceries = [
    "apples",
    "bananas",
    "clemintines",
    "dill",
    "eggs",
    "flavour",
    "grandola",
    "honey",
    "ice cream",
    "juice",
    "ketchup",
    "lemon",
    "margarine",
    "onion",
    "potatoes",
    "rosmary",
    "salt",
    "thyme",
    "vinegar",
    "watermelon",
    "pears",
    "cucumbers",
    "garlic",
    "carrots",
    "pastries",
    "eggplants",
    "milk",
    "coffee",
    "tea",
    "rice",
    "noodles",
    "lentils",
    "sweet potatoes",
    "strawberries",
    "cranberries",
    "mangos",
    "pappers",
    "zuccinis",
    "lime",
    "broth",
    "mushrooms",
    "chicken",
    "beef",
    "pork",
    "fish",
    "cream",
    "paprika",
    "tumeric",
    "cinnamon",
    "pumpkin",
    "basil",
    "tomatoes",
    "bread",
    "cake",
    "chocolate",
    "gum",
    "pineapple",
    "oranges",
    "lettuce",
    "cheese",
    "cilantro"
]

groceries = sorted(groceries)

connection = sqlite3.connect('grocery_list.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute('create table groceries (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT')
for i in range(len(groceries)):
    cursor.execute('insert into groceries (name) values (?)', [groceries[i]])
    print('added '+groceries[i])

connection.commit()
connection.close
```

Comment: You're not using `item` in the `{% for item in all_data %}` loop. You're just using `apple` in all the options.

Comment: Try `<option value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>`

Comment: It didn't help either.

Comment: looks okay to me, drop-down list shows items from `groceries` list., pls post some screen snaps where you are seeing paragraphs. your sqllite was having a syntax error , not sure if that was copy paste error to StackOverflow, so changed to following : `dl_create_tb='create table groceries (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT);'
cursor.execute(dl_create_tb)`